# FormView is completely hidden when there are no records

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formview

I have a simple FormView in a ASP.Net application. However when there are no records in the datasource, the control completely hides itself. I need to be able to have the end user add the first record view the FormView. Is there any way around this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EmptyDataTemplate to show the formView when no data is available.

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/us-en/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.emptydatatemplate(VS.80).aspx